# Python Text Dungeon Project

Tags: python

I'm making a text dungeon game for school but I'm stuck on one step. My character needs to be able to pick things up and have a maximum inventory of 3 items. Any advice would help. Thanks so much! Here is my code right now:

```
print("The evil monster Damayo has destroyed your village and stolen all your food. Him and his monster guards are at their hideout. Find them, destroy them, and retrieve your food.")
index = 1
level1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
level2 = ["4", "5", "6"]
level3 = ["7", "8", "9"]
monsters = ["monster", "monster guard", "monster BOSS"]
while True:
a = input("Type in what you want to do: " )
helplist = ["Type in left to move left, Type in right to move right, Type in     help for a list of all commands, Type in grab to grab an item"]
if a == "help":
    print(helplist)


if index == 2 and a == "right":
    print("You cannot move any further")
if index == 0 and a == "left":
    print("You cannot move any further")
if a == "left" and index > 0:
    print("You moved left.")
    index = index - 1
if a == "right" and index < 2:
    print("You moved right")
    index = index + 1
if a == "up" and index == 2:
    print("You moved up.")
    index = index + 4
if a == "down" and index <2:
    print("You moved down.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `user` dict which has like `items_in_hand` which would be `0`.
whenever you try to pick up an item,check if `items_in_hand` is less than 3 then increment it.

For better code quality you can add the `index` variable also in that `user` dict.

so you code would be like

```
user = {'index':1 , 'items_in_hand' : 0}
if a =='grab':
    if  user['items_in_hand'] < 3:
        print("You grabbed the item")
        user['items_in_hand']+=1
    else :
        print("you dont have space")
```

i havent added any error checking code.

NOTE: the best approach would be to use `objects` but one step at a time.

Comment: given what the game looks like, I think it is wiser to assume this should remain simple procedural programming.

Comment: I actually told that because i saw the line `["monster", "monster guard", "monster BOSS"]` so the developer is interested in using different `actors` with overlaping behavior,  thats why i suggested that.